# How to check the missing element in the sequence

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I am doing a project related to payroll where i will have some `payperiodnumbers` for each and every payroll that has been runned. I will show all the payrolls in a grid view with the corresponding pay period numbers.

Assume i get the following results when i binded to grid

[image]

Now from the grid if i select 1 and click on delete i would like to show an error message stating you have to delete max pay period first.

Like that if i had my max pay period number as `7` and if user selects `1,2,3,4,5,6` and try to delete i would like to display the same error. I am saving the selected `ID's` in a arraylist so can any one help me how can i check for my condition as specified. I can get the maximum payperiodid using the query but the remaining code i would like to do.

I am using `2.0` so no point of using `LINQ` here. Can any one help me

As `Azodious` pointed i am showing some condition that should work and some not

If max number is `7` and if i select `1,5,7` i would like to display an error message.

If i select `5,6,7` then it should delete that.

Comment: What should happen if max pay period number is `7` and user selects `4, 5, 7`? should the error message be dispalyed and no row is deleted OR error message be displayed after row with max pay period number = 7 is deleted?

Comment: No i would like to raise an error for that selection too. If all are in correct sequence only i should delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```C#
selectedNumbers.Sort();
selectedNumbers.Reverse();

int maxPeriodNumber = 5; // This you know
int lastValue = (int)selectedNumbers[0];

if (lastValue < maxPeriodNumber)
{
    // Highest selected number is smaller than required, warn user or throw exception
    return;
}

foreach (int val in selectedNumbers)
{
    if (val < (lastValue - 1))
    {
        // There is a gap in the numbering, warn user or throw exception
        return;
    }

    lastValue = val;
}

// When you end up here, everything is ok and you can delete the items whose numbers are in the list
```

Comment: `selectedNumbers` what should i declare this

Comment: I think that is the arraylist you are taking

Comment: You say "I am saving the selected ID's in a arraylist"... that's it.

Comment: Hi i am having small issue i have given maximum as `7` and i have my list as `1,6` but i am getting only `5` as missed element i should get `2,3,4,5` as missing elements what should i do for this

Answer (score 0):

A simple logic to display missing numbers

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(1);
lst.Add(3);
lst.Add(5);
int fst = (int)lst[0];
int last = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
{
   last = (int)lst[i];
 }
for (int k = fst; k <= last; k++)
{
 if (k == fst | k == last)
   {
   }
 else
 {
    a.Add(k);
    a.Add(" ");
 }
}
   Label1.Text = "Missing Numbers are" + " " + System.String.Concat(a.ToArray());
```